# Put image source into closest input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple images and multiple inputs, the input itself should have the closest image source inside it's value, i managed to put the image source inside the input's value, but they all have the same value, i want each input to take the closest image source in it's value, here is my code:

```js
var imgSrc = $('img').attr('src');
console.log(imgSrc);
$(".test").val(imgSrc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/1920x1080">
<input class=".test">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x400">
<input class=".test">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/950x1000">
<input class=".test">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x180">
<input class=".test">
```

Comment: `class=".test"` should be `class="test"` and I would recommend setting the `type` attribute for your inputs and close them `/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to loop through inputs:

```
$(".test").each(function() {
$(this).val($(this).prev('img').attr('src'));
})
```

Also, you can (and you should) remove .(dot) from class names in HTML.

Demo:

```js
$(".test").each(function() {
$(this).val($(this).prev('img').attr('src'));
})
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
<input class="test">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x100">
<input class="test">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x100">
<input class="test">

<img src="http://www.placehold.it/120x120">
<input class="test">
```